# Getting error, org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "." , when try to pass a list to new class in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I would like to construct a list with classes in a HQL query, but whenever I try to pass a list to the new class, the SQL generation fails by telling me `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "."`. The end result should be a list of Form objects, where each Form contains a list of votes.

If I start the query with `SELECT new com.my.class.Projection(q.id, q.otherId, q.votes)`, the q.votes will be generated as `.` in SQL which leads to an error. If, however, I change the Projection's list of votes to an int (and changing the query to `SELECT new com.my.class.Projection(q.id, q.otherId, q.votes.size)` just to get the size, it will tell me what the size is. Why can I retrieve the amount of votes, but not the list itself? Any help would be much appreciated!

Part of the SQL that will be generated:

```
Hibernate: select question0_.id as col_0_0_, question0_.other_id as col_1_0_, . as col_2_0_ from public.questions`
```

**Source code:**

Question repository

```
interface QuestionRepository : JpaRepository<Question, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT new com.my.class.Projection(q.id, q.otherId, q.votes) FROM Question q WHERE q.form = :form")
    fun findQuestionSimple(@Param("form") form: Form): List<Projection>
```

Projection

```
data class Projection(
    var id: Long = 0,
    var otherId: String
) {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question")
    var votes: List<VoteProjection>? = listOf()

    constructor(id: Long, otherId: String, votes: List<Vote>) : this(id, otherId) {
        this.id = id
        this.otherId = otherId
        this.votes = votes.map { VoteProjection(it.id, if (it.user !== null) VoteGuestProjection(it.user!!.id) else null) }
    }
}

data class VoteProjection(
    var id: Long = 0,
    var user: VoteUserProjection?
)

data class VoteUserProjection(
    var id: Long = 0
)
```

Question class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "questions", schema = "PUBLIC")
class Question {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Long = 0

    @NotNull
    var otherId = ""

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn
    var form: Form? = null

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "form")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("form")
    var votes: List<Vote> = listOf()
}
```

Vote class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "votes", schema = "PUBLIC")
class Vote {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Long = 0

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    var user: User? = null // Not relevant for this question
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main purpose for DTO projection is to efficiently map tuple into a DTO class. I don't think it works with associations.

Now, to fix your particular problem, here's what I would do:

1. Change the query to only selection question object

```
@Query("SELECT new com.my.class.Projection(q) FROM Question q WHERE q.form = :form")
```

2. Then change the `Projection` constructor

```
constructor(q: Question) : this(id, otherId) {
    this.id = q.id
    this.otherId = q.otherId
    this.votes = q.votes.map { VoteProjection(it.id, if (it.user !== null) VoteGuestProjection(it.user!!.id) else null) }
}
```

This would work, though I don't think it's the best way. It seems that you want to do some transformation which is the purpose of a [ResultTransformer](https://vladmihalcea.com/why-you-should-use-the-hibernate-resulttransformer-to-customize-result-set-mappings/).