# Quarkus Panache projection to a collection in an Entity

Tags: java, quarkus, projection, quarkus-panache

I am trying to make a projection to an attribute that has a @Collection annotation, but it always fails trying to extract the resultset. However, with simple columns, it works with no issues:

This is the class

```
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "table")
public class Table implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(length = 10)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "series")
    private String series;

    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @BatchSize(size = 50)
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(
            name = "table_word",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "name")
    )
    @Column(name = "value")
    private List<String> tWord;
}
```

And then I have a projection class:

```
@RegisterForReflection
@Setter
@Getter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TableAttribute<T> {
    private T t;
}
```

In the PanacheRepository class, it works a simple element like the series, but not the tWord:

```
public class TableRepository implements PanacheRepository<Table> {
...
        find(
                "select v.series from " + Table.class.getName() + " v"
                .project(TableAttribute.class)
                .page(Page.ofSize(limit))
        .list(); // works

        find(
                "select v.tWord from " + Table.class.getName() + " v"
                .project(TableAttribute.class)
                .page(Page.ofSize(limit))
        .list(); // does not work
}
```

And this is the error I get:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
...
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "."
...
```

Any idea?

--- Edit.

After enabling the SQL logging, this is the query:

```
// with the series:
Hibernate: 
    select
        table0_.series as col_0_0_ 
    from
        fss.table vehicle0_

// with the tWord:
Hibernate: 
    select
        . as col_0_0_ 
    from
        fss.table table0_ 
    inner join
        fss.table_word tword1_ 
            on table0_.name=sas1_.name
```

Comment: log generate sql and check what's wrong

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci updated with the SQL. It seems like it is not picking up the value from the "value" column.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60137540/getting-error-org-postgresql-util-psqlexception-error-syntax-error-at-or-near

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci not sure what is needed to change. In my code, I am not using a List of entities like in the link you post (List of Votes), in my case is a List of String, and no class with the entity, just the CollectionTable annotation with the name of the generated table.